# Graph keeps showing two different lines

Tags: microsoft-excel

I bought Excell 2010 but is confusing me a lot basically i just need to graph a

X and Y table but it is showing two lines (x is a line and Y is a line) while what i want is to show only one line  X VS Y, i dont know why it is showing two lines as if the were independent..

Can anyone please advise how to use it?

```
PS my values are

X    Y
1.0    1.5
2.8    3.9
4.2    4.6
```

[image]

I am not sure what to add here? or where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting them independently of each other. Easiest way to plot a graph is as follows:

1) create a blank graph from the "insert" tab

2) right click on the graph and "select data"

3) "add series" and highlight your x values in the 'x' input box, and y values in the 'y' input box. Series name is optional

4) select 'okay' twice. Voila.

Enjoy.

Comment: Please see what comes up after I do "Select Data" i placed a screen shot. I do not see the x and y boxes

Comment: You have to click "add" first, then they'll show up.

Comment: (see bullet 3) )

Answer (score 1):

Easier way for Excel 2010:

Use a "Scatter" chart, which in the Excel charting world is synonymous with "X-Y chart".

The Scatter chart, unlike the others, assumes that the first column or row of data are x-axis arithmetical values.

Now it's as easy as you hoped:  Select the data range, click on Insert/Scatter and click your favorite style.

Make sure your data are formatted as some kind of "number".  The default "General" should work for freshly typed data but the formatting can be a problem especially if your data came from somewhere else.

When you create the chart the "Chart Tools" tab appears on your ribbon.  The "Design" tab has 9 other pre-designed chart layouts.

If things don't look correct try clicking on the "switch row/column" button on Chart Tools/Design, left side.